# Intercepting urls in Windows Phone Browser

Tags: windows-phone-7, browser

In my app I have *two pages*: **Main Page** and **Display Page**. Each page has a *browser control*.

On Main Page the *source* of the *browser control* is *set to a website's homepage*. If the user touches a thumbnail, I want it to be shown on Display Page.

How do I **grab the address of the link** that has been clicked/touched and **send it to the browser on Display Page**?

Answer (score 2):

`WebBrowser` control has Navigating and Navigated Events.

In the Navigating handler, you can get the clicked link as e.Uri. get that and cancel the Navigation. then send that link to Display page.

```
void web_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DisplayPage.xaml?TargetUri="+e.Uri.ToString(), UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Note: By the way, sending the e.Uri is not a suggestible way. I would suggest you create a Static propety in the project and use that for sharing the links among pages.